# i need to sort array of objects in Vue with to attributes of the object but Vue go in infinite loop to sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, web, vuejs2

vue js sort array of object with attribute and try to sort that sorted array with another attribute but Vue go in infinite loop of sorting

```
chatRoomArraySorted: function() {
    console.log("func name chatRoomArraySorted");

    function compare(a, b) {
        if (a.name < b.name)
            return -1;
        if (a.name > b.name)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    return this.chatRoomsArray.sort(compare);
}

sortedArray: function() {
    this.log("sortedArray");

    function compare1(a, b) {
        return new Date(b.lastMsg.createdAt) - new Date(a.lastMsg.createdAt);
    }

    return this.chatRoomsArray.sort(compare1);
},
```

Comment: How are you calling these functions? They don't appear to be mutually recursive in your code, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: i added this function in computed and call them from html

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of code that produces the problem.

Comment: What is the code for `chatRoomsArray`?

Comment: i can't access cli when the infinite loop starthttps://stackoverflow.com/users/1497533/ippi

Comment: chatRoomArray is array of objects each object have created date and name and i need to sort the with two attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Computed properties will update whenever the value of any of the properties they depend on changes, meaning the defining function will be called again.

Since you are calling `sort()` on the `chatRoomsArray` property in both of your computed properties, you are mutating the `chatRoomsArray` array itself, triggering both computed properties to be updated. This will happen every time the function for each computed property runs, which is creating the infinite loop.

---

What you'll need to do is return a sorted copy of `chatRoomsArray` in each computed property without actually sorting the array itself.

You can make a copy of the array by calling `concat()` like so:

```
return this.chatRoomsArray.concat().sort(compare);
```

You could also use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to make a copy like so:

```
return [...this.chatRoomsArray].sort(compare);
```